How to select table rows that are simultaneously even and displayed?
I have an HTML table with odd rows colored gray.
Some rows are hidden with <tr style="display: none"> and that creates the possibility for 2 consecutively displayed rows to be of the same color, as seen in the snipped below:


.table thead th{
   background: #f6f6f6;
}

.table>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(even)>td {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>jane@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="display: none">
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>



That means that I need a way to select all rows that are odd and do not have style="display: none".
How can I achieve this result?

I am unclear what you want to do. Do you want the visible table to show what look like every other row as with color background? That is what I would have expected but it isn't what 'I need a way to select all rows that are odd and do not have display: none' says.

Using the new :nth-child(An + B of S) syntax. In your case
tr:nth-child(even of :not([style*="none"]))

Demo:


.table thead th{
   background: #f6f6f6;
}

.table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even of :not([style*="none"])) > td {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>jane@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="display: none">
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="display: none">
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>



